# creating the reference within classes

Tags: c#

I have the Class Car as shown below

```
Class Car{ String Name; String Type; }
```

I Created the car instance `"ins1"` with `Name=A` and `type=B`;
Now I created another car instance `"ins2`" with `Name=C` and `type=D`;
Another car instance `"ins3"` with `Name=D` and `type=E`

Now the objects should be refered in such as way ins1 has child ins2 and ins2 has child ins3

Once I serialize the class car ins1 instance my xml should be viewed as

```
<Car>
    <Name>A</Name>
    <Type>B</Type>
        <Car>
            <Name>C</Name>
            <Type>D</Type>
              <Car>
                 <Name>E</Name>
                 <Type>F</Type>
              </Car>
        </Car>
    </Car>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Class Car{ String Name; String Type; Car child; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a self-referencing class.

```
Class Car
{ 
    String Name; 
    String Type; 
    Car innerCar;
}
```

So for creating the hierarchy create the objects in the ff order:

```
Car3 -> Car2 -> Car1 // When serializing you can get the correct hierarchy
```

So this can be represented with the ff code.

```
Car car3 = new Car 
{
    Name = "E",
    Type = "F"
};

Car car2 = new Car 
{
    Name = "C",
    Type = "D",
    innerChild = car3
};

Car car1 = new Car 
{
    Name = "A",
    Type = "B",
    innerChild = car2
};
```

Comment: yes but if u have the parent class it doesnot refrer to all there child instances and there child instances

Comment: @ManuV see sample code. Im not yet done.

Comment: If single class has multiple child reference

Answer (score 1):

First make your class:

```
public class Car
{
    String Name;
    String Type;
    Car ChildCar;
}
```

Next use XML deserialization to fill your objects. Here's a good reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa420a9y(v=vs.110).aspx